# Mostly zero valued data and LSTM network

Tags: time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training an LSTM neural network to predict multiple timeseries.
However, most of my train timeseries have a lot of zero values. This makes the model good in predicting the future values of mostly zero timeseries, but not as good with timeseries that are not mostly zero valued.

Do you think I should delete the mostly zero valued timeseries from my train data?

Comment: Why are you using one LSTM network for all the series? You could easily avoid this by using a specific models for each individual series. The way you are doing it, you will also face problems if you have both seasonal and non-seasonal, or trend and non trend series in the same data set, not just the zeros problem you describe.

Comment: To reinforce Alex's point, clustering time series by their important features is a big help to NNs (and GBMs and random forests) in general, as compared to throwing them all into the algorithm together.

Comment: The reason i'm using one LSTM for all the series is that i'm implementing a [new LSTM based algorithm created by Amazon](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04110) that trains one model across all the series.

Comment: @YahyaMortassim You might have discovered a serious weakness in DeepAR